# How can a browser extension detect when a user opens a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working with someone else's browser extension, and trying to find the file/snippet that is responsible for detecting when a new tab is opened (Not a specific link being opened in a new tab, but just any tab--even if there's no Url.)  I'm unsure what syntax to look for, so I appreciate any helpful hints.

Thank you

Comment: The most straightforward method is [chrome.tabs.onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated).

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm!  I ran a search for that method in the project, but it doesn't appear anywhere.  I am looking through all instances where 'tabs' appears.

Comment: The code may be obfuscated/minimized.